# What is the canonical way to have wifi devices reconnect?

Tags: wifi, openbsd

On openbsd6.7 I was able to get the urtwn driver to work easily, by setting up a /etc/hostname.urtwn0. I can connect to different APs defined by separate join statements.

However, when I suspend/resume, the connection is not reactivated. likewise, when the AP goes out of range, the device does not automatically scan for new APs.

What is the canonical way to get this behavior?

Answer (score 0):

What you described is the canonical way. Configuring [hostname.if(5)](https://man.openbsd.org/hostname.if.5) with multiple `join` and `wpakey` statements is the correct way to configure Wi-Fi on OpenBSD.

After resume, you may check what is the current [joinlist](https://man.openbsd.org/ifconfig.8#joinlist) on that interface, with `ifconfig urtwn0 joinlist` command.

You may also set a [debug](https://man.openbsd.org/ifconfig#debug) flag on the network interface, to get an idea what kernel is trying to do. Messages will show up in [dmesg(8)](https://man.openbsd.org/dmesg.8).